# Filling numpy arrays with different calculated values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I initialized an empty numpy array and I want to fill it with some calculated values. My code is as follows:

```
Distance=np.empty(6,dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(0,6):
    x=hamming_distance(tst,LUT[i])
    print 'x={}' .format(x)
    print 'type_x={}' .format(type(x))
    #Distance.fill(x)
    np.append(Distance,x)
    print 'Distance={}' .format(Distance)
```

the output I get is

```
x=1
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
x=3
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
x=1
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
x=1
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
x=1
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
x=3
type_x=<type 'numpy.uint8'>
Distance=[3 3 3 3 3 3]
----------
```

and I am expecting `Distance` to be `[1 3 1 1 1 3]`. I used `np.fill` but this won't work because it will fill the array each time with `x` and the output will be `[3 3 3 3 3 3]`.

Note:
`tst` and `LUT[i]` are uint8 numpy arrays.

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with: `Distance[i] = x`? `np.append` returns a copy with the appending, so essentially you are not doing anything in your loop (other than calculating `x` and then discarding it).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather perform list comprehension:
`[hamming_distance(tst,LUT[x]) for x in range(0, 6)]` or
`np.array([hamming_distance(tst,LUT[x]) for x in range(0, 6)]).astype('uint8')`